# Ruby modules nested within classes

Tags: ruby, class, module, nested

So I've made quite a large application in Ruby, but I've realised it's quite unorganised to have everything as an instance method in one huge class, so I want to split it up into nested modules just so it's a bit more organised. I have searched on StackOverflow but it seems that it's actually not that common to use modules nested in a class.

I'm trying to understand how nested modules work by using a simpler example class:

```
class Phones

  include Apps
  include Call

  attr_accessor :brand, :model, :price, :smartphone
  def initialize(brand,model,price,smartphone=true)
    @price = price
    @brand = brand
    @model = model
    @smartphone = smartphone
    @task = 'stand-by'
  end

  module Apps
    public def camera
      @task = __method__.to_s
      puts "Took a picture!"
      self
    end
    public def gallery
      @task = __method__.to_s
      puts "Photos!"
      self
    end
  end

  module Call
    public def scall
      @task = __method__.to_s
      puts "Ring ring!"
      self
    end
  end

end
```

Then I'm trying to run:

```
s7 = Phones.new('Samsung','S7 Edge',3000).Apps.camera
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
...phones.rb:3:in `<class:Phones>': uninitialized constant Phones::Apps (NameError)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `include` calls are before the actual module definitions.

When you write a class definition, everything in there is executed immediately except stuff like method definitions. For example:

```
class Foo
  puts 1 + 1
end
```

will print 2 *immediately*, it will not wait until you say `Foo.new`.

One way to fix it would be to move the `include` calls to the end of the class definition, or the modules to the top. You can also separate out the nested modules:

```
class Phones
  module Apps
   # your stuff here
  end
end

class Phones
  module Call
    # stuff
  end
end

# just make sure the previous modules have been defined
# by the time this code is run
class Phones
  include Call
  include Apps
end
```

Comment: Moving the include calls to the bottom gives error:phones.rb:38:in `<top (required)>': undefined method Apps' for #<Phones:0x007fe9c989c4b0> (NoMethodError)`. Also, if using the second way that you suggested, in which class do you declare the initialize method and all of the instance variables?

Comment: you should not be calling include in instance scope, as it seems you're doing from your undefined method error. I meant you can move the include calls to right before the `end` of `class Phones`. Regarding the initialize, you can define this in any of the modules. When you include them you get all their instance methods combined. So if you defined multiple `initialize`, only one of them would run unless you have them call `super`.